# Callback URL in Skydrive API to localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, onedrive

I am trying to implement `SkyDrive API` into my Asp.net mvc3 application.I tried to create app in Microsoft using [this](http://cgeers.com/2012/04/29/getting-started-with-the-live-sdk-authorization/)  tutorial for implementing user authentication , but I am facing a problem in `Callback Url`, because Microsoft forces me to add a real domain and I want to use my localhost in order to develop it right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution for my problem, I used [pageKite](http://pagekite.com) to solve my problem. `pagekite` gave me an alternative to my localhost by mapping my localhost to a real domain. so I added that domain to my app in Microsoft and its working.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could add a fake domain to your

- /etc/hosts (Linux)
- C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts (windows)

file. Just add the following lines:

```
127.0.0.1   www.yourfakedomain.de
```

After adding that line you can choose in Microsoft OneDrive App-Center something like

```
http://www.yourfakedomain.de/blabla.php
```

as your redirect uri.

Since your operating system thinks that domain belongs to localhost you will be able to get your authentication code just normally at your local test domain ;-)

Answer (score 0):

How would SkyDrive call code on your local machine?

One way to do it is to first mock SkyDrive in your application -- that is, you don't call the real SkyDrive, just a service that you have running locally that acts as if it is SkyDrive. You can use that to develop and debug your application to some extent.

Then you can deploy your application to a test server on the Internet, so that SkyDrive can do the callback, and you can test it there and make the necessary modifications before you deploy to an actual production server.

Comment: I am using Skydrive Api which is included in `Microsoft.live` & `Microsoft.Live.Web` libraries, How to mock skydrive in my application?