# Using localhost at Microsoft apps as a Redirect domain

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, onedrive

I am trying to build an application with `SkyDrive Api` using ASP.Net. I started with the help of this tutorial https://github.com/geersch/LiveSDK/tree/master/src/part-1  I tried to create an application in `Microsoft Live Connect Developer Center` and because my application is a web application I need to set `Redirect Domain` the problem is I am still at developing mode i tried to add localhost to `Redirect Domain` but I failed.

I asked [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16279427/callback-url-in-skydrive-api-to-localhost) and answer it by solving the problem with [PageKite](https://pagekite.net/) but this not helping me right now because I am facing problems with `PageKite`

Any suggestions about how to solve this problem? Or how to develop an application in with `SkyDrive Api`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use windows hosts file to map a domain to localhost. The hosts file is found under `Windows\System32\Drivers\etc`. Add a line similar to this then save the file.

```
127.0.0.1      MyDomain.com
```

Browsing to `MyDomain.com` should open your root IIS default page, You can set the redirect URI to map to your app path in OneDrive e.g. http://example.com/myapp

Check this link for more info: [MSDN Web apps - Testing web apps locally](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn659751.aspx#Testing_web_apps_locally)